# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery but need filtered results

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate

I've got the error message for the following codes

as in a nested query

```
FROM(
    SELECT  SUM(CASE (select TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt from WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition where WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition.EmployeeID = Employee_ID) 
                WHEN NULL THEN 0 
                WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE GrossPay / (select TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt from WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition where WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition.EmployeeID = Employee_ID) * 200 
            END
            ) AS [Paid FTE],
        Employee_ID, 
        Position_ID, EarnedPeriodEndDate
        FROM
        WDHRISods.WD.ActualDistributions
```

how to modify to avoid the error?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that generates the error:

```
     SELECT SUM(CASE (select TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt from WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition where WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition.EmployeeID = Employee_ID) 
                    WHEN NULL THEN 0 
                    WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                    ELSE GrossPay / (select TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt from WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition where WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition.EmployeeID = Employee_ID) * 200 
                 END
                ) AS [Paid FTE],
          Employee_ID, Position_ID, EarnedPeriodEndDate
    FROM WDHRISods.WD.ActualDistributions
```

Replace this with a `JOIN` and aggregation:

```
    SELECT COALESCE(ad.GrossPay * 200 / NULLIF(wp.TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt, 0), 0) as [Paid FTE],
          ad.Employee_ID, ad.Position_ID, ad.EarnedPeriodEndDate
    FROM WDHRISods.WD.ActualDistributions ad LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT wp.EmployeeId, SUM(TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt) as TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt
          FROM WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition wp
          GROUP BY wp.Employee_ID
         ) wp
         ON wp.EmployeeID = ad.Employee_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I've get errors Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspWDBen_Elg_Aud125, Line 110
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspWDBen_Elg_Aud125, Line 120
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspWDBen_Elg_Aud125, Line 127
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspWDBen_Elg_Aud125, Line 158
Incorrect syntax near 'HCAPd'. and wp.Employee_ID is not a valid field. Thank you

Comment: @JackieGMa . . . This code snippet has no `AND` in it; hence, it is not the cause of that error.  This should just drop in where your current subquery is.

Answer (score 0):

I have have the TotalBasePayAnnualizedAmt from a table from WDHRISedw.edaHR.WorkerPosition with the same EID and complete the full time rate calculation